# Mysql DB structure for Real estate website

Tags: mysql

I have a real estate website where location table has 4 fields

- region
- department
- city
- zipcode

If someone add property in 2 cities which has different department but same region and same zipcode, then when properties are searched in that region or zipcode, it should list all those properties

What will be best DB structure for this plz

Answer (score 0):

A simple trivial solution is to put an index in whatever field you need to search by.

Put an index to `region`
Then when a user searches say by region, it will quickly to a WHERE region=xxx.

Put an index to `zipcode`
Then when a user searches say by zipcode, it will quickly to a WHERE zipcode=xxx.